# TableView not showing new data loaded from plist after dismissing from other view

Tags: ios, uitableview

My First View is a UIViewController i have a UITable View in it and it works just fine.

From the first view i push another view, in that view i select a group name then the view dismiss, what i want is when i select the group name from the second view the first view loads the values of that group name to the table view, this is the code i use and its not working

the second view code

```
- (IBAction)sendNames:(id)sender {
if (!keyValue) {
    NSLog(@"Didnt Select Any Group To Send");
    return;
}

ViewController *theInstance = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[theInstance setGroupName:keyValue];
[theInstance ReceivedGroup:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

//tried that option and didnt work too, i added the rest of the code in the viewDidLoad
//[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RG" object:nil];
}
```

***keyValue*** is NSString that been set on ***tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath***

the first view

```
- (IBAction)ReceivedGroup:(id)sender {    

NSString *path = [self dataFilePath];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray *tempArray = [dict objectForKey:groupName];

nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[nameArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];
[nameTable reloadData];

NSLog(@"Group Name : %@",groupName);
NSLog(@"Array : %@",nameArray);
}
```

***groupName*** is NSString

In the log i get the ***groupName*** and the ***nameArray*** printed

but the tableView is empty.

***EDIT: I fixed the problem and posted my answer***

Answer (score 0):

Your viewcontroller "theInstance" will be deallocated immediately after calling sendNames: so nothing's gonna happen. You should rather pass a pointer of your first viewcontroller to your second viewcontroller (e.g. set it as a property) and perform all operations on this viewcontroller.

subclass UITableViewController

```
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *firstViewController;
@end
```

if using storyboard segues implement in your first viewcontroller :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   ((SecondViewController *) segue.destinationViewController).firstViewController = self;
}
```

sendNames: should then look like this:

```
- (IBAction)sendNames:(id)sender {
if (!keyValue) {
    NSLog(@"Didnt Select Any Group To Send");
    return;
}

ViewController *theInstance = self.firstViewController;
[theInstance setGroupName:keyValue];
[theInstance ReceivedGroup:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

//tried that option and didnt work too, i added the rest of the code in the viewDidLoad
//[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RG" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it ?

Comment: i did what you said but still the table doesn't show the data, while i can see the data printed in the log perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it by sending the ***keyValue*** using ***NSNotificationCenter***

Here is my code now

For The Second View

```
- (IBAction)sendNames:(id)sender {
   if (!keyValue) {
       NSLog(@"Didnt Select Any Group To Send");
       return;
   }
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RG" object:keyValue];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then On The First View

```
- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *Key = [notification object];
    nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [nameArray removeAllObjects];

    NSString *path = [self dataFilePath];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *tempArray = [dict objectForKey:Key];
    [nameArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];

    [self.nameTable reloadData];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[nameTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1 inSection:0];
    [nameTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"RG" object:nil];
}
```